# SSIS package fails to execute when run as a job

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm trying to build a SSIS package in sql server to run an Excel import for me to a certain table when I follow all the steps using an import wizard and the import runs just fine. I save it as a file and try to run it again by double clicking it - it runs fine again. And yet when i setup a job in sql agent i get the following error:

```
> Message Executed as user: myusername Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
> Package Utility  Version 14.0.3025.39 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) 2017
> Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:52:02 AM  Error:
> 2019-04-12 08:52:02.33     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: packagename
> Connection manager "SourceConnectionExcel"     Description: SSIS Error
> Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
> 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access
> Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified
> error".  End Error  Error: 2019-04-12 08:52:02.33     Code: 0xC020801C
> Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - Query [29]     Description: SSIS
> Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
> AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
> "SourceConnectionExcel" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may
> be error messages posted before this with more information on why the
> AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2019-04-12
> 08:52:02.33     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task 1
> SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Source - Query failed validation and
> returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2019-04-12
> 08:52:02.33     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1
> SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed
> validation.  End Error  Error: 2019-04-12 08:52:02.33     Code:
> 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task 1      Description: There were
> errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
> execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:52:02 AM  Finished:
> 8:52:02 AM  Elapsed:  0.297 seconds.  The package execution failed. 
> The step failed.
```

What i did - I've configured the Credentials for my user and created a proxy user with also my credentials, which are able to access all necessary files and tables. Am I missing something? I've also tried to run it in 32 Bit mode - but no luck: [image: config],

Comment: Couple questions come to mind.  Where is the excel file located and is that location accessible from the server?  Does your proxy account have the necessary access to that location where the excel file is located?

Comment: Here there are chances that your account is the so called interactive one - means it requires to pass the challenge-response authentication mechanism (a security measure) which would not be possible in the case of the unattended job. Thus the job fails. Note: you should use the proper, unprivileged [service] account and better create a SSIS package as part of a project. Unprivileged means it has enough rights only to do this operation.